# Не подтягиваются данные из файла эксель в другой файл (если файл с данными закрыт),

Tags: excel, данные

Почему то при закрытом файле не подтягиваются данные в другой файл.

Объясняю:
Есть документ с данными (пусть файл будет называться бюджет), он лежит в папке, например, Папка1.

В Папке1 помимо этого файла есть другие папки, например, папка1.1 и папка1.2.

В Папке1.1 есть другие папки, например, Папка1.1.1.

И вот в папке 1.1.1 лежит файл, в этот файл (пусть будет называться департамент) должны подтянуться данные из файла бюджет.

При этом, в папке 1.1.2 есть другие файлы, которые имеют связь с файлом бюджет - и там все подтягивается правильно.

Формулы одинаковые, связь в файле департамент имеется с файлом бюджет.

Файл Департамент не подтягивает данные из файла Бюджет если файл бюджет закрыт.

Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема

Comment: *в чем может быть проблема* Именно в том, что файл не открыт. Прямые формулы иначе не умеют. В отличие от внешних источников данных.

Answer (score 0):

Файлы - источники не должны быть открыты. Приложение Excel само забирает оттуда данные.

При открытии файла должен появляться запрос на обновление данных. Если он не появляется - что-то не так.

Проверьте в меню "Данные" статус ссылок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый день!
Прислала скрин в комментарии к обсуждению

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его как принятый.